# What is the status of C++20 coroutines support in Clang?

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++, c++-coroutine

According to cppreference.com ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_features ) Clang has partial support of C++20 coroutines since version 8:

[image: Clang coroutine support]

But if in Clang trunk (which is upcoming version 13) I write

```
#include <coroutine>
```

it results in the error( https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rTfjbarKz ):

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.0.0/../../../../include/c++/12.0.0/coroutine:334:2: error: "the coroutine header requires -fcoroutines"
#error "the coroutine header requires -fcoroutines"
```

And if I add `-fcoroutines` flag in the command line, then Clang complains( https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qMrv6nMzE ):

```
clang-13: error: unknown argument: '-fcoroutines'
```

Is there any way to start using C++20 coroutines in Clang?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that the first error is in the GCC standard library, and from that it can be deduced that the `-fcoroutines` option is for GCC not Clang.

To build with the Clang libc++ you need to add the option `-stdlib=libc++` instead. But that will lead to the `<coroutine>` header file not being found instead.

Since Clang coroutines is still in the "experimental" stage you have to include `<experimental/coroutine>`.

So there are two things you need to change:

- Use the Clang libc++ (`-stdlib=libc++`)
- Include the experimental header file (`#include <experimental/coroutine>`)

Also note that since coroutines are experimental, the symbols defined in the header file will be in the `std::experimental` namespace.

Comment: Thanks. The correct include is ```#include <experimental/coroutine>``` (without 's' at the end)

Comment: Do you know if clang will support libstdc++'s coroutines eventually? Or does using coroutines mean you always have to use libc++ if you're compiling with clang?

Comment: I don't think that Apple will ever support libstdc++ again, they said that this is legacy. They go with libc++ because this is not poisoned by the GPL license.